# How to paste tabular data into the "new row" of a DataGridView with AllowUserToAddRows set true?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

We use DataGridViews throughout our UI... most are data-bound to some backing table... most of those through a BindingSource.

They all have supported Ctrl+C to Copy tabular data out (so you can paste into Excel or Word tables, etc.).  That was easy... it's built-in... just set MultiSelect true and ClipboardCopyMode to EnableWithAutoHeaderText (or one of the other Enable... settings).

Our users have requested us to similarly support Ctrl+V to Paste tabular data copied from Excel etc.  Unfortunately, that is not nearly so easy.  I created a generic utility method PasteStringTable(DataGridView) that will pull the tabular data off the Clipboard and then paste it into the selected cells of the argument DataGridView.  I have that working except for one key issue:

If the DataGridView has AllowUserToAddRows set true, and the user is in that magic "new row" at the bottom, then I wanted to add rows for each row on the Clipboard.  But the problem is, nothing I do programmatically ever seems to get it to actually add that row... I've tried everything that I can think of (or find via Bing or Google):

(1)  I tried doing BeginEdit / EndEdit on the DataGridView.

(2)  I tried first setting the DataGridView.CurrentCell to the cell I was about to edit, then DataGridView.BeginEdit(true), then edit the cell by setting its Value property, then DataGridView.EndEdit().

(3)  I tried doing #2, but where I did SendKeys.Send(value) instead of .Value = value.

(4)  I tried doing DataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true) in the middle of the above.

(5)  I tried modifying the underlying data source first by manually doing DataGridView.Rows.Insert(index, 1) to try to force in a new row before I pasted into it... but that throws an exception since my DataGridViews are data-bound.  (NOTE:  I do not want to hard-code specific access to the underlying data because I want it to work like Paste where the data copied lines up visually with the DataGridView's columns.)

(6)  Many other variations...

In the end, most attempts result in the same behavior:  you can see that the bottom row gets modified... you can see the first row of the data you copied show up in that magic "new row", until you click out of the row and the row goes blank again... unless you manually edit it, it never gets added to the underlying data.  Even if I try doing SendKeys.SendWait(...), it still doesn't act like it would if I typed in that data.

How do I programmatically get that magic "new row" to act like it would if I typed in the pasted in data??

(Surely I am not the first person to want to paste tabular data into DataGridViews.)

Comment: Could you upload a small example would be easier to help

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, this is the pattern I came up with that works well in most cases.  This is pure guesswork, though, so if anybody knows how it is supposed to work, please let us know.  Anyway, here's what I've got working:

```
                        DataGridViewCell cell = dgv[colIndex, rowIndex];
                        if (!cell.ReadOnly) // && (evenIfNotSelected || cell.Selected)) // Selected is not stable in some cases
                        {
                            if (!cell.OwningRow.IsNewRow)
                                cell.Value = cellData;
                            else
                            {
                                dgv.CurrentCell = cell;
                                dgv.BeginEdit(true);
                                dgv.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
                                //SendKeys.SendWait(cellData);
                                cell.Value = cellData;
                                //dgv.CommitEdit(???);
                                dgv.EndEdit();
                                //PSMUtility.DoMessages();
                                // Do it again to try to overwrite the default value that might get injected by EndEdit adding the row
                                cell.Value = cellData;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: to set cell value, try this: `cell.Value = newValue; dgv.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true); dgv.BeginEdit(true); dgv.EndEdit();`

Answer (score 1):

Also i try many solution and finally it's work in my case.

```
private void calculationGrid_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)e.KeyChar == 22 && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {
                calculationGrid.CurrentCell.Value = Clipboard.GetText().Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim();                      
                calculationGrid.BeginEdit(true);
                calculationGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
                calculationGrid.EndEdit();
            }
        }
```